# Updating ormlite_config.txt after adding new table

Tags: android, ormlite

I need to upgrade the schema of released application by adding new table. I'm using table config file (`ormlite_config.txt`).

- Is there a way to update also the `ormlite_config.txt` file after adding new table to the schema?  Do I have to update it?
- Or maybe it is possible to instantiate`OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` passing the updated version of config file - with description of new table which does not exist yet, but is going to be added in `onUpgrade()` call?

Comment: Look here also. This is how to set it up on Android Studio http://stackoverflow.com/a/31946807/976550

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question. If you add a new table (or change the schema of an existing table) you will need to regenerate the `ormlite_config.txt` file. It won't happen automagically.

If the schema changes in the config file, you will need to add code to your `onUpgrade()` method to adjust any running databases.  You will also need to increment your database version so `onUpgrade()` gets called at all.

For more information, see the Android upgrade schema docs:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/upgrade-schema

Comment: What's the purpose of the "ormlite_config.txt" file? I mean, both the creation and upgrading of the tables are made by us, using onCreate and onUpgrade , as shown on their example: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-examples/blob/master/android/HelloAndroid/src/com/example/helloandroid/DatabaseHelper.java